# How To Display All Javascript Array Data as a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, file-io, tostring

I have a 2D Array in Javascript that I'd like to display as a string for the user, and hopefully add the ability to read in another Array later (effectively trying to save and load all objects in the array).

I'll be honest, I have absolutely no idea when it comes to file encoding, but so far I've tried `keyframes.toString()` and `keyframes.frame.join()` to no avail.

The only output that give me is `[object Object]`. Something about this is making me think that dealing with 2D arrays is different to a simple list of values, but like I said, I don't really know..

How do I go about displaying an array as pure text in Javascript?

Comment: try JSON.stringify(array). this gives u a json string.

Comment: Absolute star, that's exactly what I was going for.

Comment: thanks. if it worked for u then let me post this as a solution and you can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using `JSON.stringify` if you just want a string representation of your array. here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bkr4qc3u/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to "flatten" the array first.

```
var flattened = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]].reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});
// flattened is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code:

```
function join2DArray(arr,sep1,sep2)
    {
    if (sep1 == undefined || sep1 == null) sep1 = "";
    if (sep2 == undefined || sep2 == null) sep2 = "";
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
        if (arr[i].join) arr[i] = arr[i].join(sep2);
        }
    return arr.join(sep1);
    }

function split2DArray(str,sep1,sep2)
    {
    if (sep1 == undefined || sep1 == null) sep1 = "";
    if (sep2 == undefined || sep2 == null) sep2 = "";
    var arr = str.split(sep1);
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) arr[i] = arr[i].split(sep2);
    return arr;
    }

var my_arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
var my_arr_joined = join2DArray(my_arr,"|",",");
alert(my_arr_joined);
var my_arr_resplit = split2DArray(my_arr_joined,"|",",");
alert(my_arr_resplit[0][1]);
```

Hopefully it will give you an insight into how to do it for your code.

Answer (score 0):

use this function

pass `str` parameter if you want to join with a special char or string

```
function joinArray(arr, str)
{
    if (str == undefined || str == null) str= "";
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        if (arr[i].join) arr[i] = joinArray(arr[i], str);
    return arr.join(str);
}
```

use it like

```
var output = joinArray(keyframes);
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76pjnywj/)**